# UnitTesting a CocoaTouch Static Library in Xcode 4.3 fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS at 0x0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a static lib for an iOS project in XCode 4.3, but can't get unit testing to work.

I create a brand new static lib project and immediately do "Product -> Test". But this fails with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at address 0x0 (see screenshot).

[image]

Also, when I build the project the .a product never appears, it always stays red. This may be why the tests are failing.

Am I missing some magical step in order to develop a static lib?

Comment: Works for me using Xcode 4.2. You should really indicate what version of Xcode and what SDK you're using.

Comment: Sorry, it's xcode 4.3, I've updated the post. Maybe I should try downgrading it.

Comment: It's likely just a problem with the project template. Try setting a breakpoint on the first line and stepping through each test until you find the line that crashes.

Comment: I've added a breakpoint all over the place, but it never hits any of them. I think it's failing before running any code.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've solved my own problem.

I had to go to 'Edit Scheme' by clicking the scheme drop down menu in the toolbar. Then I changed the debugger for 'Test' from LLDB to GDB. Now the tests run as expected.

Seems a bit of an odd default for testing if it doesn't work.

[image: Change 'Test' debugger]